# coupled nonlinear systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

[image]**Let us assume that we have the following nonlinear system, depicted in the above figure:**

$\ddot{x_{11}} = a\cdot Sigm(x_{31}-x_{21})-b\cdot\dot{x_{11}}-c\cdot x_{11}$

$\ddot{x_{21}} = d\cdot Sigm(x_{11})-k\cdot\dot{x_{21}}-g\cdot x_{21}$

$\ddot{x_{31}} = a\cdot(Sigm(x_{11})+p_1)-b\cdot\dot{x_{31}}-c\cdot x_{31}$

**and let us assume that we want to couple it with an identical one:**

$\ddot{x_{12}} = a\cdot Sigm(x_{32}-x_{22})-b\cdot\dot{x_{12}}-c\cdot x_{12}$

$\ddot{x_{22}} = d\cdot Sigm(x_{12})-k\cdot\dot{x_{22}}-g\cdot x_{22}$

$\ddot{x_{32}} = a\cdot(Sigm(x_{12})+p_2)-b\cdot\dot{x_{32}}-c\cdot x_{32}$

**Info about it:**

all $x$ represent potential, $\dot{x}$ could represent current for constant capacitance

$p_1$ is the output of the second system which ends up as input for the first

$p_2$ is the output of the first system which ends up as input for the second

and $Sigm(x)$ is a sigmoid function

**The Question:**

How could we express the occurring system after the coupling and rewrite its equations, using the relationship potential-current between the state variables and their derivatives?

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a homework question..

Comment: I have tried to model it in matlab using:
1. the traditional way: 12 equations. 
2. knowing in which equations the coupling presents itself, and using a loop for from 1 to 2 to solve it.

However, for a system with more than 2 coupled sub-systems neither of these is the way to go. I was trying to find a pattern which could be useful although the system contains a sigmoid function